unable to capture the erroneous record number while processing huge text file
the input for this job is a huge .txt file.
#!/bin/ksh  


 
while read -r line
  do
    awk ' BEGIN {FS= ","} 
    $2 ~ /[mM]/  {     

    if  ($12 ~ /[1-9]+/ )
      {
        SECNext=$13
        if ( SECNext != SECPrev )
          {
            SECPrev=SECNext
            $3=substr($3,5,4)"-"substr($3,1,2)"-"substr($3,3,2)  

          }
        else
          {
            printf ("%s\t Same SEC Occured \n",$0) >>$var1$var2
          }
      }
    else
      {
        printf ("%s\t No SEC  for this trem\n",$0) >>$var1$var2
      }
    }
             ' 2>>$var1$var3
 done<$tmp_file>$dir$file".dat"

 rc="$?"
 

How ever, i have done minor changes to this script to capture standard error returning from awk using this  ' 2>>$log_dir$err_fname and capturing it in an custom error file.
But unable to capture for which record the awk is writing standard error. need to capture that input line among huge counts of lines from input txt file.
provide a way to know at which line it's failing?

Please post the script with the problem, rather than describing the changes you made that caused the problem.

This is also quite a bit of code. Please only post the part relevant to the problem.

Are you sure you're using Linux? I don't think the Linux version of awk prints that error message, it's the AIX version.

Instead of capturing stderror, just check that the line has the correct number of fields. (NF >= 19)

>>$log_dir$log_fname doesn't work inside the awk script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script for how to use shell variables inside an awk script.

The line number of the bad line is in this message: The input line number is 3.567832e+04.

Which is quite strange because it's 35678.32, and line numbers can't have fractions.

@barmar, you are correct. it's AIX

while ... read line ... do awk  ' .... ' is an antipattern.

correct line number has been updated to 3.87172e+07. hesitant to decipher while forming question. sorry for inconvenience.

Calling awk once per line in a shell while-read loop is very much like if you bought a car to get to work and then pushed your car back and forth to work every day. Definitely do not do that! Your script must take forever to run and it has issues that http://shellcheck could help you with.

Hang on... you're not passing "$line" to awk so that while read will read the first line of input then awk will read the rest so you're not actually calling awk 1 line at a time but awk won't see the first line of input. Get rid of the while read and then if you don't want awk to do anything with the first input line then add NR==1{next} to the top of the awk script.

Thank you @Barmar your link about usage shel variable could help lot to understand and fix the issue.

As the file is so large and awk is giving line number in exponential format, it won't indicate the exact line number in the input file but nearly it gives as it rounds off the number.

Shell variables $log_dir and $log_fname aren't replaced between 'quotes'. Use awk-option -v to pass values, e.g.:
awk -v log_dir="$log_dir" -v log_fname="$log_fname" '
    ...
    printf ("%s\t No UPC  for this item\n",$0) >>(log_dir log_fname)
    ...
'

Edit: the question has been edited since, albeit inconsistently.

Add a check for the correct number of fields at the in the awk script.
    awk ' BEGIN {FS= ","}     # set a delimeter to comma
    NF < 19 {printf("Line too short: Line #: %d, length: %d, contents: %s\n", NR, NF, $0) > "/dev/stderr"; nextline}
    $2 ~ /[mM]/  {     ### Check if it is an item level "M" ($2 - second field)


Did you try looking that input line in question? With something like:
sed -n '3567832p' 
Assuming I converted the scientific notation correctly this should show you the exact line where the script is failing.

3.567832e+04 is 35678.32.

this awk is writing this similar stderror daily, even though $rc is 0. i am struggling to know why awk is writing non-zero code every other day while the stderr is similar daily. and the line number thing i checked. no clue, it just giving a random line just like 9150,D,03312024,01,FCT,M,Y,1,1

@Barmar Oh, right you are. Unless I'm mistaken though, the line numbers should always be integers. shouldn't they? So it seems like 35678.32 can't be the right line number, unless .32 means something different in this context like column number or something.

@Barmar the line number has been updated correctly now. kindly consider 3.87172e+07
